# Error when trying to run my Flutter App with my m1 mac

Tags: macos, flutter, apple-m1, podfile

I get the following Error everytime i try to run my Flutter App. I tried literally so much to fix it but still the Error isn't fixed.

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
[!] Unable to find a target named `testing_gowtham` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did find `Runner`.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:108:in `compute_targets'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:40:in `compute_results'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1189:in `block (3 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1187:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1187:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1185:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1185:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1180:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:106:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this :

**Cocoa Pods Installation in M1**

- sudo gem install cocoapods
- sudo gem install ffi
- arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
- sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin

**Install ffi**

- sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

**#update repo**

- arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update

**Flutter iOS builds**

- flutter clean
- flutter build ios

**Re-install dependency in iOS folder of flutter project**

- arch -x86_64 pod install

Comment: I've done all of this now i run into following error Message: /GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'audioplayers' not found
    @import audioplayers;
     ~~^~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete

Could not build the application for the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Please `follow this article` to install the coca-pods. I also follow this article when I setup the flutter on my Macbook M1.

-> make sure you have enabled the rosetta in your terminal (discussed in the following article)

https://medium.com/codex/simple-way-to-use-cocoapods-on-m1-ac9e22cf7e1c