# cannot run Flutter application on iOS simulator / Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, macos, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2HgH.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4adHi.png)

**Addition is below**

I make Flutter app. and then recently it happens cannot to run appication on iOS simulater. I guess the reason is Xcode upgrade but don't know well.

do you have any idea to help it? thank you.

**// environment //**

- PC:2021 Macbook air (apple silicon)
- MacOS:12.0.1 - recently updated
- Visual Studio code:1.62.3
- Xcode:13.0 -recently updated
- Flutter:2.5.3

**// done //**

- restart PC & Xcode & Vscode
- reflessh keychain
- List item

delete DerivedData

**// flutter doctor //**

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-arm, locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at /Users/osanaidaisuke/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (7 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/osanaidaisuke/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 13.0, Build version 13A233
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.29.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 12 Pro (mobile) • B2A1F8F1-D8D0-41D4-B58F-B3AC18E0E3CE • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-0 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.55

• No issues found!
```

**// debug console //**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            3.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E4530DD9-3EEB-4DFF-895E-2284A8BE131C, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:C9AEED53-CAAE-4357-9507-508EA93199C8, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BE2B5D9F-C78E-4BE6-8720-66D6B37A7DBB, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FA89C5C9-39C1-4F00-91CA-45924F0484C3, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2A37CCE9-6BA7-4BB9-9430-DB5EBCBE8D3E, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A641FC6E-451B-43CD-97AE-2427F4E71FC6, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:01C67389-E045-469F-88AF-4CE2980CE0B0, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D14130F2-B8BE-4FC2-8F99-537686236900, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6DE2DBDC-6BB8-41FF-A7EA-122E06ED3D09, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7FFC4095-7D08-4353-81CD-957F563FAF6A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D397D581-E8C0-4EC4-BFE5-F05161D28A32, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:055C8666-A3D5-4AF3-B52C-1F67909F3876, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B2A1F8F1-D8D0-41D4-B58F-B3AC18E0E3CE, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EEBEE112-736C-4D00-AEDC-7E4874390DB5, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CB3FC6AE-A5A7-4973-A758-8D86ABAD2CEE, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:659B04AA-DF4B-405E-B926-4FED18271CDD, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DFF4E533-9009-43D9-B905-7CC12C765C4E, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AF7C323B-3BF0-4BAB-9F6B-1C7DFA62DB41, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:37DEFCE1-2E9E-42BB-91FE-93D0C7C92203, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:55EA657F-A586-4634-95D7-75B26B73DFC4, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:ACA87D06-CF69-490F-9DE7-12989F10CB62, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00008103-0003452226EA001E }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Failed to package /Users/osanaidaisuke/code/project-name/listview.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
```

addition

Every project file don't have Podsfile. Is this normal? And I could not install cocoapods.

**/ sudo gem install cocoapods //**

```
Password:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20211205-49831-16satjc.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-ffi_c-dir
        --without-ffi_c-dir
        --with-ffi_c-include
        --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
        --with-ffi_c-lib
        --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
        --enable-system-libffi
        --disable-system-libffi
        --with-libffi-config
        --without-libffi-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in `block in try_link0'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in `try_link0'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:672:in `try_ldflags'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1832:in `pkg_config'
        from extconf.rb:9:in `system_libffi_usable?'
        from extconf.rb:42:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.4/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68170472/13547175

Comment: I faced the same problem. try this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993852/4470297](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993852/4470297) it's worked for me

Comment: I could not install cocoapods normally. So I installed -v1.8.4 cocoapods .

Comment: but [sudo gem install ffi] also does not work well.

Comment: ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20211205-52216-g0o51d.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

Comment: current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
make DESTDIR\= clean

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
make DESTDIR\=
make: *** No rule to make target `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin21/ruby/config.h', needed by `websocket_mask.o'.  Stop.

Comment: make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/websocket-driver-0.7.5/gem_make.out
@ ~ %

Answer (score 0):

FIXED, for my case is file permission problem, with flutter admin helped.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94692

but the root cause i think that is the error prompt is not obvious,
you may take a look at the investigation steps to see why,
and you may find yours solutions

Comment: thanks. I didn't know `flutter --verbose` command. it may give me some hint.

Comment: The following build commands failed:PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script

/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-acctwqhdfcmkyphhyoedbuzbziun/Build/Intermediate s.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh (in target  'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Answer (score 0):

Try to update pods, go to your ios folder, run   `pod deintegrate`, and then
run '`pod install`'. if this does not help then run `pod update` or '`pod repo update`'. try to find which package is giving issues, and changes their versions.

Comment: you mean ios folder is the one in each flutter project right?

Comment: This error can happen on any project including new Flutter project.

Comment: yes , every flutter project has ios folder in it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved by upgrading Flutter --version from 2.5.3 to 2.8.1.

Source URL: https://minpro.net/your-flutter-checkout-has-local-changes-that-would-be-erased-by-upgrading